# Importar Clases en PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Estoy creando un script en powershell que va a hacer uso de clases como esta:

```
Class Auto {

    [string]$Marca
    [string]$Color

    Auto ([string]$m,[string]$c) 
    {
        $this.Color = $c
        $this.Marca = $m
    }
}
```

Pero quiero escribir cada clase en un archivo diferente y hacer uso de ella en el script principal como normalmente se hace en otros lenguajes de programación.

¿Cómo puedo conseguir esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para incluir un fichero **Auto.ps1** en otro **main.ps1**, debes conocer la ruta de absoluta de **Auto.ps1**, no se permiten rutas relativas.

Sin embargo, puedes calcular la ruta a partir del comando invocado:

```
# Obtener el directorio base donde están los scripts a partir del que lo invoca
$base = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent

# Incluir las referencias necesarias
. ($base + ".\Auto.ps1")
```

Así, tus comandos pueden estar en una estructura de directorios como

```
MisScripts\
   Util\
     util.ps1
   Extra\
     extra.ps1
   actualizar.ps1
   listar.ps1
```

entonces, para incluir **util.ps1** desde **listar.ps1** escribirías en este último

```
. ($base + ".\Util\util.ps1")
```

Un ejemplo completo podría ser dejar en la siguiente estructura

```
Ejemplo\
  Util\
    Auto.ps1
  main.ps1
```

donde **Auto.ps1** contiene

```
Class Auto {

    [string] $Marca
    [string] $Color

    Auto ([string] $m,[string] $c)  {
        $this.Color = $c
        $this.Marca = $m
    }

    [void] Report() {
        Write-Host ("AUTO: " + $this.Marca + " (" + $this.Color + ")")
    }
}
```

y **main.ps1** contiene

```
# Obtener el directorio base donde están los scripts a partir del que lo invoca
$base = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent

# Incluir las referencias necesarias
. ($base + ".\Util\Auto.ps1")

[Auto]::new("Audi", "Azul").Report()
```

entonces, al llamar desde cualquier sitio a **main.ps1** se obtiene

```
C:\Users\josejuan>powershell d:\datos\tmp\main.ps1
AUTO: Audi (Azul)

C:\Users\josejuan>
```

Answer (score 1):

A partir de PowerShell 3.0 (desde 2008) existe una variable automática llamada [$PSScriptRoot](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2014/02/20/use-psscriptroot-to-load-resources.aspx), que apunta al directorio donde script esta guardado.

```
# importar 'auto.ps1' que esta ubicado en la misma carpeta que este script

. "$PSScriptRoot\auto.ps1"

# aqui auto ya esta disponible
```

También funciona con sub carpetas..

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\modulos\auto.ps1"
```

Ten en cuenta que apunta a la carpeta donde se encuentra el Script, y no a la carpeta donde se esta ejecutando el script, por lo que puedes construir tu script usando rutas relativas.